# PayPal Linking error while integrating Paypal SDK for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I downloaded the latest paypal IOS SDK using below

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

I added frameworks as specified in the sample..

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-i386-master.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-i386-master.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-i386-master.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-i386-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also tried with

Go to Targets -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags
Add -lc++ & -ObjC to it

I have SDWebImage in my project..

Please suggest any ideas where I went wrong..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 7):

go to yourProjectName then BuildSetting and put -lc++ -ObjC on other Linker Flags

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks bro.. it's a small solution but work like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Targets -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags Add -ObjC -l"PayPalMobile" -l"Pods-PayPal-iOS-SDK" -l"c++" -framework "AVFoundation" -framework "AudioToolbox" -framework "CoreLocation" -framework "CoreMedia" -framework "MessageUI" -framework "MobileCoreServices" -framework "SystemConfiguration"

Comment: If you are not using cocoapods, just remove that Pods line.

-ObjC -l"PayPalMobile" -l"c++" -framework "AVFoundation" -framework "AudioToolbox" -framework "CoreLocation" -framework "CoreMedia" -framework "MessageUI" -framework "MobileCoreServices" -framework "SystemConfiguration"

Comment: my problem was gone. I missed frameworks. nice answer

Answer (score 0):

I would look at step 4 in the [instructions](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK). Specifically, make sure that all the frameworks can be found by adding them explicitly or enabling automatic linking.